# User SVG.js to scale, then translate will make it wrong position

Tags: svg.js

I use svg.js

After I calling g.scale(4), then g.translate(x, y) will go to the wrong position, then how can I do it ok?

There's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/87gqz3no/34/

Use mousewheel to zoomin the canvas, then drag to move it. but it goes wrong position.

Drag the white background. It works ok.

Then use mousewheel to zoomin the whole canvas. Then drag the background... zoomin..., drag..., the position of the background(the root `g` element) goes wrong.

F12 to see the console, of setting and getting.

```js
var $canvas = $('#mycanvas')
var g = SVG('mycanvas').size('100%', '100%').group()
// draw a rect
g.rect(200, 40).translate(100, 100).fill('red')


var click = {};  // click pos of screen 
var g_pos = {};  // click pos of container element `g`
var scale = 1;  // scale of container element `g`


// mouse down to record the position
$canvas.on('mousedown', function(e) {
  click = {x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY};
  g_pos = {x: g.x(), y: g.y()};
  scale = g.transform().scaleX;
  
  // when mousedown, add event listener
  $canvas.on('mousemove', move);
  $canvas.on('mouseup', up);
})


// set the new position of the g
function move(e) {
  // delta pos of mouse move
  var delta = {
    x: e.pageX - click.x,
    y: e.pageY - click.y
  };
  
  // calculate the new position of g
  // even if I force set scale to 1, also not work.
  // scale = 1;
  var x = g_pos.x + delta.x / scale;
  var y = g_pos.y + delta.y / scale;
  
  console.log("set pos of g:", x, y, "delta:", delta, 'scale:', scale);
  g.move(x, y);
  console.log("get pos of g:", g.x(), g.y());
}


// when mouseup, remove event listener
function up(e) {
  $canvas.off('mousemove', move);
  $canvas.off('mouseup', up);
}


// mousewheel to zoom
$canvas.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
      var delta, diff, last_scale, max_scale, min_scale, per;
      delta = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta && (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1)) || (e.originalEvent.detail && (e.originalEvent.detail > 0 ? -1 : 1));  // delta position of mouse wheel
      last_scale = g.transform().scaleX;
      per = .1;
      min_scale = .5;  // min scale
      max_scale = 8.6;  // max scale
      diff = delta > 0 ? per : -per;
      return g.scale(Math.min(Math.max(last_scale + diff, min_scale), max_scale));
    })
```

```css
html,
body,
#mycanvas {
  width: 99%;
  height: 99%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#mycanvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.5/svg.min.js"></script>
<div id="mycanvas"></div>
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There is [svg.panzoom.js](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.panzoom.js) for your pan/zoom problem and [svg.draggable.js](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.draggable.js) for dragging elements

Comment: @Fuzzyma May Thanks! I successfully use svg.panzoom.js to drag the background canvas and mousewheel to zoom it. There's no need to use svg.draggable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy the comment which answers the question:

Why reinvent the wheel? There is [svg.panzoom.js](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.panzoom.js) for your pan/zoom problem and [svg.draggable.js](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.draggable.js) for dragging elements

```
let canvas = SVG('idOfDiv').panZoom()

let rect = canvas.rect(100, 100).draggable()
```

Comment: Yes, it works.

But, `.panZoom()` seems it doesn't return this, so can not use as chain.

let g = SVG('idOfDiv').group()

g.panZoom()

let rect = g.rect(100, 100).draggable()

Comment: It definitely SHOULD return `this`. So if it does not, doublecheck and open a bug report!